# Query IEnumerable as IEnumerable<Type>

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin

I have a problem I need to solve efficiently.

I require the index of an element in an IEnumerable source, one way I could do this is with the following

```
    var items = source.Cast<ObjectType>().Where(obj => obj.Start == forDate);
```

This would give me an IEnumerable of all the items that match the predicate.

```
   if(items != null && items.Any()){
       // I now need the ordinal from the original list
       return source.IndexOf(items[0]);
   }
```

However, the list could be vast and the operation will be carried out many times. I believe this is inefficient and there must be a better way to do this.

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: You CANNOT do this with `IEnumerable` efficiently. That is why we have other interfaces, like `ICollection`. For one, `IEnumerable` maybe implemented with a Database connection/ORM or it can be implemented with a LinkedList. Neither of which can an efficient algo be implemented for.

Comment: @Aron - However, if the underlying type is also `ICollection<T>` then LINQ uses the efficient way when it can.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has posted an answer. Many are good reference for the future. However, in this instance i have implemented a binnary search due to the specifics of the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, it's good to forget about Linq and go back to basics:

```
int index = 0;

foeach (ObjectType element in source)
{
    if (element.Start == forDate)
    {
        return index;
    }

    index++;
}

// No element found
```

Comment: I have implemented a binnary search, this prevents the need for casting all of the items in the list to the required type and reduces memory overhead for the operation. Sometimes it is good to forget about Linq.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq, you can take the index of each object before filtering them:

```
source
    .Cast<ObjectType>()
    .Select((obj, i) => new { Obj = obj, I = i })
    .Where(x => x.Obj.Start == forDate)
    .Select(x => x.I)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, this is not really efficient, the following will do the same without allocations:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (ObjectType obj in source)
{
    if (obj.Start == forDate)
    {
        return i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code sample was invalid: since `items` is an `IEnumerable`, you cannot call `items[0]`. You can use `First()`. Anyway:

```
var items = source.Cast<ObjectType>()
.Select((item, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, ObjectType>(index, item))
.Where(obj => obj.Value.Start == forDate);
```

and then:

```
if (items != null && items.Any()) {
    return items.First().Key;
}
```

Comment: Why use `KeyValuePair<int, ObjectType>(index, item)`? Why not just `new { index, item }`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because it is a struct, but whatever you prefer. It doesn't really matter, I suppose.

Comment: Why does a `struct` help?

Comment: @Enigmativity In this case, it doesn't because you're only taking the first item. But if you're enumerating a million items it will avoid creating a million objects. (It's kind of a reflex that I used `KeyValuePair`, I didn't think about using an anonymous type)

Comment: Keep in mind that `KeyValuiePair` doesn't implement `Equals` & `GetHashCode` so it can't be used for many of the operators that require comparison. Anonymous types do implement them. It's best to avoid `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this multiple times I would create a lookup for the indices.

```
ILookup<DateTime, int> lookup =
    source
        .Cast<ObjectType>()
        .Select((e, i) => new { e, i })
        .ToLookup(x => x.e.Start, x => x.i);
```

Now given a `forDate` you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = lookup[forDate];
```

Since the `lookup` is basically like a dictionary that returns multiple values you get the results instantly. So repeating this for multiple values is super fast.

And since this returns `IEnumerable<int>` you know when there are duplicate values within the `source` list. If you only need the first one then just do a `.First()`.

Comment: Right, index them up. How would this differ from ToDictionary() ?

Comment: @bit - It differs because a dictionary only maps the key to a single value and this maps any key to zero or more values (thus getting all the indices for duplicate values). If you do a lookup with a key that doesn't exist you get an empty enumerable rather than an exception.